# Docker installation on RHEL 7.2 and file system requirement

Tags: docker, redhat, filesystems, xfs, docker-machine

We have old `RHEL` machine `version 7.2`

And we prepare to install docker service on this server

The problem is that server's filesystem was created with `ftype=0` parametre and docker requires `ftype=1`

One option of course is to format the disk with mkfs and create new file system with `ftype=1`

But we want to stay with the original OS and not format the disk

Second option is to perform the step as defined in the post - https://superuser.com/questions/1321926/recreating-an-xfs-file-system-with-ftype-1/1321963#1321963

**But this steps are risky and required server to be down**

We are searching for third alternative in order to implement the docker installation on rhel version 7.2 in spite `ftype=0`

Interesting direction could be for example by adding a new disk to the server and create `XFS` file system, with *ftype=1* ,  but we are not sure how to defined the docker installation on the additional disk (because this disk is actually without OS).

We  will happy to get any other ideas out of the box.

Comment: It's even more risky to run your server with software that is missing years of security fixes. Do not run RHEL without a subscription (use CentOS instead). You might not even be able to install Docker if you haven't got a RHEL subscription.

Comment: you are right , but because some sensitive issues ( that are not technical issues )  we cant upgrade the rhel version to higher version ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a new XFS filesystem on your new disk and mount it at `/var/lib/docker`. Then you do not need to make any changes to the Docker configuration, as that is the default directory for Docker volumes, images, containers, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to add an additional disk formatted with the correct `-n ftype=1` flag.

Mount the disk somewhere and point Docker to that location by setting:

```
{ 
   "graph": "/path/to/your/docker" 
}
```

in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

The fstype flag should be relevant only for the overlay filesystem so it shouldn't matter that the docker binary is stored on a filesystem formatted without that flag.

Comment: did you try it? and this is something that was done ?

Comment: in your example what is the meaning of - "graph"" ? , that should be in /etc/docker/daemon.json

Comment: No, I didn't test that. graph defines the path where Docker will store the overlay fs

Comment: do you have some documentation about this approach?

Comment: @KingDavid You can create the new XFS filesystem and mount it at `/var/lib/docker`. Then you do not even need to make any change to the daemon.json file.

Comment: do you mean the new disk ( with ftype=1 ) will mount to /var/lib/docker ?? and thats it?

Comment: @Michael Hampton better if you post your answer so all users can see and give you up vote , I think your solution is very simple and brilliant